# Trying to update a label in tkinter class

Tags: python, class, tkinter, scope

Im new to python and this forum. I tried searching a solution for the errors i get in my code but this only made me try a lot of different stuff, still i couldn't get my label updated.

Now i think it has something to do with my inability tot properly define a variable at the class level. But to be honest, i have a hard time grasping the concept of class, self, global, local etc. So this may well add to my confusion.

I cut the code that gives me the errors from my larger program to post here. I hope some of you can enlighten me what i do wrong. Sorry in advance for breaking python code etiquette, i'm still learning.

Some of the things i tried i commented out in the posted code...The code i posted here gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/smaller example.py", line 35, in <module>
    app = cbgui(root)
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/smaller example.py", line 8, in __init__
    self.initUI()
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/smaller example.py", line 23, in initUI
    labelupdate = Tkinter.Label(frame,  width = 50, textvariable = self.var)
AttributeError: cbgui instance has no attribute 'var'
```

My code:

```
import sys, Tkinter, tkFileDialog


class cbgui(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.master = master
        self.initUI()
        self.var = Tkinter.StringVar()
        #self.var = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.var.set = "hello"

    def UpdateLabel(self):
        #var.set = "bye"
        self.var.set = "bye"

    def initUI(self):
        self.master.title("a small update test")
        frame = Tkinter.Frame(self, relief=Tkinter.RAISED, borderwidth = 1)
        frame.pack(fill = Tkinter.BOTH, expand = 1)
        self.pack(fill = Tkinter.BOTH, expan = 1)

        #labelupdate = Tkinter.Label(frame,  width = 50, textvariable = var)
        labelupdate = Tkinter.Label(frame,  width = 50, textvariable = self.var)
        #labelupdate = Tkinter.Label(frame,  width = 50, text = "hello")
        labelupdate.grid(row=3, column=2)

        labelspace = Tkinter.Label(frame, width = 1)
        labelspace.grid(row=3, column=3)

        UpdateButton = Tkinter.Button(frame, text="Update label",  command = self.UpdateLabel)
        UpdateButton.grid(row=3, column=4)

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("700x300+10+10")
app = cbgui(root)
Tkinter.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create `self.var` *before* you call `self.initUI` since `initUI` uses `self.var`

```
def __init__(self, master):
    Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.master = master
    self.var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    #self.var = Tkinter.StringVar()
    self.var.set("hello")
    self.initUI()
```

Comment: Okay...wow the error is gone, but my code still didn't do what was intended. So i looked at the var.set commands en discoverd a stupid mistake...it's self.var.set("hello") instead of self.var.set = "hello". With your help and the changes in the var.set...it WORKS!!!!! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @frettiggestoord -- Yeah ... Forgot about that.  Good catch :)